# Serial Upvoting: Should I be concerned?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

Not that I complain, but I gained > 200 pts through upvoting within a couple of minutes today. Is that just an enthusiastic user, or something systemic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry, that's indeed most likely a new user, unfamiliar with Stack Exchange rules, who wanted to award you bonus points because they saw a particularly helpful answer of yours. The correct way to do so is a [bounty](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/bounty); mass upvoting posts because they're written by a specific person; you should [vote for the content, not for the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232).

The votes will be reversed somewhere during the (UTC) night; see [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/295232). If it doesn't for some reason, not even after waiting another day, you can flag one of your posts for moderator attention and they will take care of it. There is of course no penalty for being serially upvoted by accident.